# C# ASP.NET for loop issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

In my code behind I have a list of names...(Tracy, Michelle and Tiffany)

and I have a string called names and each name gets added to the string, but it displays like this (Tracy Michelle Tiffany)

How would I get it after each name it gives a comma and before the last one, put and..

here is some of my code

```
    string names = "";

    for(int i=0; i< GroupOfPeople.Count; i++)
    {
         GroupOfPeople nm = (GroupOfPeople) nm.GroupOfPeople[i];
         names += nm.FirstName;                        
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `names += ", " + nm.FirstName`?  And then throw an `if` condition in to make that an `"and"` before the last name?

Comment: Without seeing more code... `string.Join()` ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)), combined with selecting/projecting your list of names into `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like

```
for(int i=0; i< GroupOfPeople.Count; i++)
        {
            GroupOfPeople nm = (GroupOfPeople) nm.GroupOfPeople[i];
                if(i < GroupOfPeople.Count - 1)
                    names += nm.FirstName + ", ";
                else
                     names += " and " + nm.FirstName;

         }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use .NET 4.0 or newer, you can use `String.Join` that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
var nameList = new List<string>();
for(int i=0; i< GroupOfPeople.Count; i++) {
    GroupOfPeople nm = (GroupOfPeople) nm.GroupOfPeople[i];
    nameList.Add(nm.FirstName);
}
var names = string.join(", ", nameList);
```

It is hard to say without seeing the interface of `GroupOfPeople` if it is possible to do this without creating an explicit list. If there is a way to select all first names from `GroupOfPeople` using LINQ, plug that expression into the last line in place of `nameList`:

```
var names = string.join(
    ", "
,   GroupOfPeople.Cast<GroupOfPeople>().Select(nm => nm.FirstName)
); //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ The above cast may be unnecessary
```